# What are the good and bad effects of following hierarchical structure strictly?

Tags: communication, work-environment, company-culture, productivity, teamwork

Certain managers and leads, in particular, enforce certain rules that create a culture of hierarchy. For Example, one has to keep his reporting manager informed before having any cross team interaction, or even when inviting someone for a meeting.

I understand that it is required to keep all the stakeholders informed whenever any important decision in the project  is to be taken. However, my question especially is with respect to minor discussions and clarifications with people in different teams, mostly in a casual and informal way. Some leads and managers look down upon such practices too, under the pretext that people might be busy and need to be approached officially. How far is this justified? Is it not a good idea to have a pretty flat culture with people approaching each other more freely, rather than moving through formal channels and hierarchy all the time?

Answer (score 2):

This completely depends on the corporate culture and is different in every company. There could be important reasons managers need to maintain the strict hierarchy that you are unaware of, and they company as a whole has decided that maintaining the hierarchy is more important than efficiency. This is particularly true in work that requires security clearances or work that could easily fall victim to industrial espionage.

My work is often cross-functional and I also find frustration in having to "go through channels" for seemingly trivial communications.

Changing corporate culture is very difficult and the impetus has to come from very high up in the company (i.e. from the CEO and downwards from there). If you don't have the CEO's ear, find someone lower in the structure who does (like someone in the HR office, preferably the VP) and talk to them about the culture in the company. They may not be aware that this is happening at your level.

Answer (score 0):

Some workplaces embrace a complete respect of hierarchy.
Some others don't really care if you skip some levels.
In some other, senior management routinely has friendly lunches with entry level workers.
It's all a matter of the predominant company culture. Go against it, and you might end up looking for another job.